# check if the key is exist, after that insert or update

Tags: mysql, mybatis

I have a fifteen-column table in my database.

and I have a key which has a quality of auto-increment.

What I want to do is.. check if the table has a column with the key and insert if exist, else update.

I applied SQL syntax which I found here to my code.. but it never works.

here's the sample code below.

```
    insert into report (col1, col2, col3.......col14) values ('value1','value2', ....'value14')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1=values('changedValue1'), col2=values('changedValue2')....col14=values('changedValue14');
```

I excuted this code in Mybatis, but it returns MySQLSyntaxErrorException..

Comment: Please add what is the error message along with the exception that you are getting in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have syntax error in your query.the query should be like,

```
insert into report (col1, col2, col3.......col14) values ('value1','value2', ....'value14')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1='changedValue1', col2='changedValue2'....col14='changedValue14';
```

for more info visit the following link : 
[Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists)